# Creating a language extension for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to create an extension or plugin for Eclipse that gives support to a specific language? Where i can find information about that? Also, can i repackage Eclipse, along with that plugin, and distribute the new package, just like PDT, for example?

Comment: Have a look at Xtext: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs
There is a section "Implementing Support for Your Own Language" at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely have a look at Xtext which allows you quite easily to get first grade ide support for your own langage.

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. In fact support for specific languages is implemented as plug-ins. See [eclipse platform plug-in developers guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=/2) and then search for details. Or look for some book like [eclipse plugins](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/).
You can repackage and distribute new package. In fact [eclipse license](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html) gives you more freedom  in this than for example GPL.